# Prove that $\sqrt{n} \le \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \le 2 \sqrt{n} - 1$ is true for $n \in \mathbb{N}^{\ge 1}$

Tags: inequality, induction, problem-solving, natural-numbers

I'm trying to solve [these induction exercises](http://www.maths.ox.ac.uk/files/imported/prospective-students/undergraduate/practice-problems/pdf/induction1.pdf) proposed by the department of mathematics of Oxford University. I don't know how to give a valid proof for the third one which says the following:

> Prove that for $n \in \mathbb{N}^{\ge 1}$: $$ \sqrt{n} \le
>  \sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{\sqrt{k}} \le 2 \sqrt{n} - 1 $$

My first approach has been to convert the summation into a function in terms of $n$ so that I could find the maximum and minimum values in the interval. However, there doesn't seem to be an easy way to express the summation as a function. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The induction start is easy. Then it is sufficient that you show $$\sqrt{n+1} - \sqrt{n} \leqslant \frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}} \leqslant 2(\sqrt{n+1}-\sqrt{n}).$$

Comment: See also: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/509840/use-induction-to-prove-that-1-frac-1-sqrt2-frac-1-sqrt3, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/420733/proving-that-frac1-sqrt1-frac1-sqrt2-cdots-frac1-sqrt, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/56335/proving-sum-limits-k-1n-frac1-sqrtk-ge-sqrtn-with-induction (and maybe other posts on this site).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since
$$
\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}=\frac1{\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}}\tag{1}
$$
we have
$$
\frac1{2\sqrt{k+1}}\le\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}\le\frac1{2\sqrt{k}}\tag{2}
$$
Summing $(2)$ yields
$$
\sum_{k=2}^n\frac1{2\sqrt{k}}\le\sqrt{n}-1\le\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\frac1{2\sqrt{k}}\tag{3}
$$
which implies
$$
\sqrt{n}-1+\frac1{2\sqrt{n}}\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{2\sqrt{k}}\le\sqrt{n}-\frac12\tag{4}
$$
Therefore,
$$
2\sqrt{n}-2+\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{k}}\le2\sqrt{n}-1\tag{5}
$$
Combining $(5)$ and
$$
\sqrt{n}\le\sqrt{n}+\left(n^{1/4}-n^{-1/4}\right)^2=2\sqrt{n}-2+\frac1{\sqrt{n}}\tag{6}
$$
yields
$$
\sqrt{n}\le\sum_{k=1}^n\frac1{\sqrt{k}}\le2\sqrt{n}-1\tag{7}
$$

Comment: Please clarify item 3

Comment: Note that $$2\sqrt{k}\le\sqrt{k+1}+\sqrt{k}\le2\sqrt{k+1}$$ Take the reciprocal of this inequality and apply $(1)$. This gives $(2)$. $(3)$ is just the sum of $(2)$ from $k=1$ to $k=n-1$.

Comment: Please clarify the transition to the item3 with step by step

Comment: Which part is giving you trouble, the sum of the left part, the middle part, or the right part?

Comment: the middle part

Comment: This is a [telescoping series](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telescoping_series). $$\begin{align}\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}(\sqrt{k+1}-\sqrt{k}) &=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sqrt{k+1}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sqrt{k}\\ &=\sum_{k=2}^n\sqrt{k}-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\sqrt{k}\\ &=\left(\sqrt{n}+\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\sqrt{k}\right) -\left(\sqrt{1}+\sum_{k=2}^{n-1}\sqrt{k}\right)\\ &=\sqrt{n}-\sqrt{1}\end{align}$$

Answer (score 1):

In answering [a similar question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/530432/how-to-approximate-this-series) I proved that:

$$\frac{2}{3}N\sqrt{N}\leq\sum_{n=1}^{N}\sqrt{n}\leq\frac{4N+3}{6}\sqrt{N}.$$

This can be achieved through induction, partial summation or a Riemann sums+convexity argument. For this problem, let's try the third way. $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x}}$ is a convex function over $[1,N]$, hence the trapezoidal rule overestimates the integral $\int_{1}^{N}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}$:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{1}}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}}\right)\geq 2\sqrt{N}-2,$$
that is just:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\geq 2\sqrt{N}-\frac{3}{2}+\frac{1}{2\sqrt{N}}\tag{1},$$
while the fact that $f(x)$ is decreasing gives:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\leq 1+\int_{1}^{N}\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x}}=2\sqrt{N}-1,\tag{2}$$
establishing the following tight inequality:

> $$2\sqrt{N}-\frac{3}{2}\leq \sum_{n=1}^{N}\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\leq 2\sqrt{N}-1.$$

Comment: Just to be clear, this proof does not rely on induction as the perfectly fine answer of Eupraxis1981 does. It is written just to show an efficient technique for bounding certain sums.